# selectionchange with concatenated columns in data grid

Tags: c#, concatenation, selectionchanged

hey guys need your help

TEXTBOX VALUES

brand | model | description

A         |      B  |        C

BRAND AND MODEL ARE CONCATENATED as Equipment

Equipment | description

```
A B   |       C
```

with selectionchange, what do i need to do in order to separate Brand and model to display their values in Different textboxes

select concat(Equipment.EqName , ' ', Equipment.EqBrand  , ' ', Equipment.EqModel) as Items ,Equipment.EqDesc ,Qty, UnitPrice
 from POItems inner join Equipment on  POItems .EqID = Equipment.EqID where POItems.POID is NULL
 group by  POItems.POItemsID, Qty, Equipment.EqName , Equipment.EqBrand , Equipment.EqModel ,Equipment.EqDesc , UnitPrice

Comment: How are concatenating the values? You just need to do reverse of it. You need to split the string by the same character which you use to join them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: select concat(Equipment.EqName , ' ', Equipment.EqBrand  , ' ', Equipment.EqModel) as Items ,Equipment.EqDesc ,Qty, UnitPrice  
 from POItems inner join Equipment on  POItems .EqID = Equipment.EqID where POItems.POID is NULL
 group by  POItems.POItemsID, Qty, Equipment.EqName , Equipment.EqBrand , Equipment.EqModel ,Equipment.EqDesc , UnitPrice                                                         this is my query so far...can you show me on how to split them

Answer (score -1):

> **what do i need to do in order to separate Brand and model to
>   display their values in Different textboxes**

```
select concat(Equipment.EqName , ' ', Equipment.EqBrand , ' ', Equipment.EqModel) as Items ,Equipment.EqDesc ,Qty, UnitPrice
from POItems inner join Equipment on POItems .EqID = Equipment.EqID where POItems.POID is NULL group by POItems.POItemsID, Qty, Equipment.EqName , Equipment.EqBrand , Equipment.EqModel ,Equipment.EqDesc , UnitPrice
```

In the above SQL you are concatenating `EqName`, `EqBrand` and `EqModel` together. So you need to **specifically include** the individual columns you want (i.e. Brand and Model). This SQL should work:

```
select Equipment.EqBrand, Equipment.EqModel, concat(Equipment.EqName , ' ', Equipment.EqBrand , ' ', Equipment.EqModel) as Items , Equipment.EqDesc ,Qty, UnitPrice
from POItems inner join Equipment on POItems .EqID = Equipment.EqID where POItems.POID is NULL group by POItems.POItemsID, Qty, Equipment.EqName , Equipment.EqBrand , Equipment.EqModel ,Equipment.EqDesc , UnitPrice
```

Once that is done, you can bind that data into your existing `DataGrid` and hide those columns so that the user can't see them.